# How to edit wordpress v4.5 be Html page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, cpanel

[image]

i have problemm with my wordpress site. i install it on softclaus in cpanel... i want edit my wordpress be html. i dont know where i can find the edit. this wordpress is v4.5 . how to edit be html?? i tried to find it on the web. but they wordpress is different with me? ... my wordpress is only twenty sixteen theme. how do i can edit ???? please help me!!!!

Comment: WordPress is a CMS, so which part of your site do you want to edit? You can create a page and add/edit the HTML there.

Comment: why on earth would anyone upvote this?

Comment: there is no option to edit the home page of my site... why?

Comment: That is because each design has different settings. Appearance -> Customize, all of these settings are the default adjustment settings associated with your theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress is what is considered a CMS (Content Management System). Basically what this means is everything is pre-designed for you. If you are trying to edit or create a new HTML page, you would simply click Create new Page/Post. Each option will either create a blog or a webpage depending on the template. Now if you are looking for a whole new theme you click on appearance -> themes -> new themes.

If you are trying to create a new design you could do that by utilizing FTP and creating a child directory which is shown here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-wordpress-child-theme-video/